# How to insert a perl object directly to mongodb?

Tags: perl, mongodb, object, hash

I would like to insert an object to mongodb , but since this is an object, not an simple hash ref ,so it throws an exception when I insert.I know , it is because perl object is actually an  blessed hash ref.So , I wander if there is a way for me to automatically convert perl object to hash ref ,or if there is a convenient  way to insert perl object into mongodb ?

what I am dealing with is a perl module named [SWISS::ListBase](http://swissknife.sourceforge.net/)(a perl module used to parse gene bank data),when I directly use codes below to insert:

```
$collection->insert($obj);
```

it throws an exception:

```
type(SWISS::ListBase) unhandled at /usr/local/lib/perl/5.14.12/MongoDB/Collection.pm line 168,<> chunk 1.
```

Yes ,I can manually extract the data I need from SWISS::ListBase and construct the hash all by myself,but it is really tedious.So I tried to insert this object directly and got such exception.
So , any suggestions?

Comment: Could you show us some code? From what I see [here](https://metacpan.org/pod/MongoDB), it looks quite straightforward.

Comment: Yes ,from the document , it just uses insert() to insert hash reference, but perl's object is a blessed hash ,not a common hash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is a **Perl object serializer**. Have a look at this [Comparison of Perl serialization Modules](http://blogs.perl.org/users/steven_haryanto/2010/09/comparison-of-perl-serialization-modules.html)

Or, to use enterprise buzzwords **marshal / unmarshal** : [Marshalling and Unmarshalling complex data structures in perl](https://confluence.slac.stanford.edu/display/IEPM/Marshalling+and+Unmarshalling+complex+data+structures+in+perl)

Anyway, the idea is that there are things that can not be serialized, like an open socket, or a reference to an opened file, or an open database connection.

Comment: Many thanks.I have a look at Data::Dump,and it is just what I need.Thanks!

Comment: @Vico_Wu, maybe you'd like to look at `freeze()` and `thaw()` as well from the [Storable](http://perldoc.perl.org/Storable.html) core module.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure you just need the hash reference, nothing else, stored in MongoDB, you could try this:

```
my $copy = { %{$obj} };
$collection->insert($copy);
```

I didn't tested with MongoDB although... but it seems reasonable to work since the test below shows the difference between them:

```
C:\>perl -MData::Dumper -MJSON::Syck -E "$obj = { um => 1, dois => 2, tres => [ qw(um dois) ] }; bless $obj, 'Foo::Bar'; say JSON::Syck::Dump($obj); $copy = { %{$obj} }; say JSON::Syck::Dump($copy); say Dumper($t); say Dumper($new)"
{"um":1,"dois":2,"tres":["um","dois"]}
{"um":1,"dois":2,"tres":["um","dois"]}
$VAR1 = bless( {
             'um' => 1,
             'dois' => 2,
             'tres' => [
                         'um',
                         'dois'
                       ]
           }, 'Foo::Bar' );

$VAR1 = {
      'um' => 1,
      'dois' => 2,
      'tres' => [
                  'um',
                  'dois'
                ]
    };
```

JSON::Syck seems to DWIM, I'm not sure why MongoDB couldn't do the same.